# Viruses through MONO

Tags: 14.04, wine, mono, monodevelop

Whole day i was reading about Viruses on Linux ( UBUNTU 14.04 LTS : my os ), so i got to this topic that viruses can effect your computer through WINE( which allows you to run windows app on linux) i understood it, but, 2 days ago i installed mono complete for C# development, and im using PINTA for small paint type things, when i went to PINTA folder, it had dll files and its launcher was in .exe format, after getting more deeper , i found out that its runned by mono, mono is running that .exe. i googled it and searched it everywhere, didnt find this topic being discussed on MONO, so i though i should ask it myself

so same question goes for mono, like wine can MONO help viruses to infect my Linux Machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found out this link which answered my question,  mono sandbox runs untrusted code with trusted code,  it was made for moonlight and they have even mentioned stackoverflow in it

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/sandbox/